# ¿ El nombre "TextBoxHelper" no existe en el espacio de nombres "clr-namespace:Namespace"

Tags: c#, wpf, namespace

estaba haciendo una dependency property para los TextBox entonces hice la clase que estaba en el namespace PeriodicTable, al intentar usarlo en WPF me saltaba el error que la clase TextBoxHelper no forma parte de el namespace PeriodicTable, cuando claramente si ya que hasta el mismo editor me marca que puedo poner ahí TextBoxHelper. Aquí esta la clase TextBoxHelper:

```c
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace PeriodicTable
{
    public static class TextBoxHelper
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty WatermarkProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Watermark", typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxHelper),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnWatermarkPropertyChanged));

        public static string GetWatermark(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(WatermarkProperty);
        }

        public static void SetWatermark(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(WatermarkProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnWatermarkPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (d is TextBox textBox)
            {
                textBox.Loaded += (s, args) => AddWatermark(textBox);

                textBox.GotFocus += (s, args) => RemoveWatermark(textBox);

                textBox.LostFocus += (s, args) => AddWatermark(textBox);

                if (textBox.IsLoaded)
                {
                    AddWatermark(textBox);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void AddWatermark(TextBox textBox)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(GetWatermark(textBox)))
            {
                textBox.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Gray;
                textBox.Text = GetWatermark(textBox);
            }
        }

        private static void RemoveWatermark(TextBox textBox)
        {
            if (textBox.Foreground == System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Gray && textBox.Text == GetWatermark(textBox))
            {
                textBox.Text = string.Empty;
                textBox.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y aquí esta el código que me da error en WPF.

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PeriodicTable"

<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="83,58,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" local:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Hola"/>
```

Es muy raro ya que como dije el editor de código si que me marca que puedo poner eso ahí.

Gracias.